# how to load page after getting data in controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
'use strict';

(function () {
    angular
        .module('systemStatusApp')
        .config(function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('app.isomicroservices', {
                    url: 'isomicroservices',
                    templateUrl: 'app/isomicroservices/templates/isomicroservices.html',
                    controller: 'isomicroservicesCtrl',
                        resolve : {sampledetails : function(){
                            console.log("resolve"); 
                        }
                            return "asdf";
                          }
                });
        });
})();
```

--

```
'use strict';

(function () {
    angular
        .module('isomicroservices')
        .controller('isomicroservicesCtrl', 'sampledetails',function (sampledetails) {



            console.log("sampledetails"+sampledetails); 

        });

})();
```

Comment: Please ask proper question. read documentation of stack, how to ask question

Comment: i think this question is already in queue for closing .. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your query

Answer (score 0):

I think your code maybe can be:

```
'use strict';

(function () {
angular
    .module('isomicroservices')
    .controller('isomicroservicesCtrl', ['sampledetails', function (sampledetails) {

        console.log("sampledetails"+sampledetails); 
    });
}])();
```

Comment: resolve: {
             repeatValue: ['isomicroserviceService','$q', '$timeout', 
                           function(isomicroserviceService,$q, $timeout){
                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                 
                    deferred.resolve( isomicroserviceService.getServerScopeList());
                 return deferred.promise;
             }]
         }

Comment: i have added this code in router but still with out featching values  view is loading

Comment: please help me to fix this issue